# htacess restricted to one referrer BUT allow access to login page and whole site on Wordpress

Tags: .htaccess

I create a new thread as it's a new question regarding the excellent answer given by @Mrwhite i now face a new issue when trying to insert a new directive in order to allow access to my login page (and after login to the whole site) for user not coming from my allowed referer.
i did have success by adding below code :

```
# Serve everyone from specific-domain (and internal requests)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} login [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://www\.your-domain\.com/ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://www\.specific-domain\.com/
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# everybody else receives a forbidden 
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

But with it i can only access login page and once logged in the home page but if i try to browse the site and access lets say `https://your_domain/page/>`or any other page it return a `NO FOUND` error message.
I tried to update my permalinks but i didn't help.

I dunno why i do access the home but not the page inside the website, if anyone has a clue it would be greats as it's the last part i need to solve.

Thanks

Comment: You should either ask this in your existing question, or make this one here fully self-contained. And please don’t copy full answers into “new” questions, that makes very little sense for a Q&A site such as this to begin with.

Comment: thanks @CBroe, is this format better as i feel it's a new questions and i don't want to stack questions as former one has been solved

Comment: What do you mean, you tried to update your permalinks - is this within a CMS like WordPress? Is this your full .htaccess now?